# laravel sentry create user with custom password field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I am trying to create user with Sentry, But with a my password field on users table as user_password.

```
$user = Sentry::createUser(array(
    'full_name'   => $input['name'],
    'email'    => $input['email'],
    'user_password'    => $input['password']
));
```

But it keeps on throwing the error,A password is required for user [***@***.com], none given.

And when I change user_password to password, it throws error, Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> try it
> $user = Sentry::register(array(
>     'full_name'   => $input['name'],
>     'email'    => $input['email'],
>     'password'    => $input['password']
> ));
> ```

Comment: Still its throwing error, "A password is required for user [****@***.com], none given.", The issue is my password field is user_password. So is there anyway to set config to mention that my password field name is user_password?

Comment: change your password field into sentry database replace your field name if you want to with password field

Comment: you meant to modify sentry scripts to use "user_password" instead "password" as field?... I was looking for something more generic like, to specify the field name in app/config/sentry/config.php or similar way..